# Treatment of parameters %h:%p for switch -W in multi hop jumps in ssh

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, proxy, tunneling

With

```
ssh -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -oProxyCommand=\"ssh -W %%h:%%p -oProxyCommand=\\\"ssh -W %%h:%%p root@jmp1\\\" root@jmp2 \" root@jmp3" root@jmp4
```

you can do a multi jump from `jmp1` to `jmp2` to `jmp3` to `jmp4`.

Why does `%%` work here?

Comment: Check the `-J` option instead, it simplifies a lot (unless your openssh version is too old): `ssh -J jmp1,jmp2,jmp3 jmp4`

Comment: Thx, yes, I know the `-J` option. I'm particularly interested in this one here.